# Package 'xterm' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, package-management

I am puzzled as to why this package is not in the system. I've installed xorg and I'm trying to use xterm, but it's not found and the shell suggests that I install it through `apt-get`, but when I try it says

```
Package 'xterm' has no installation candidate
```

I have tried to find information online but to no avail. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: I added this line to my sources.list and i could install xterm: `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe`

Comment: @jpezz: Please don't add the answer to the question. The linked duplicate question should be more than enough for future readers to discover suitable answers. Thanks.